# cv2.imwrite does not write correct pixel values

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am examining INbreast database and I am tryint to convert DICOM images to JPEG format. Here is how DICOM images should look like when reading them as numpy array with following code:

```
ds = dicom.dcmread(img_path)
plt.imshow(ds.pixel_array)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But when I try to write image in JPEG format as follows, I am getting wrong pixel values:

```
cv2.imwrite("{new_img_path}.jpeg", ds.pixel_array)
img = cv2.imread("{new_img_path}.jpeg")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: what are ds.pixel_array.shape and ds.pixel_array.dtype before imwrite?

Comment: @unlut shape is (4084, 3328) and type is numpy.ndarray.

Comment: @StefanRadonjic not type(ds.pixel_array), instead ds.pixel_array.dtype

Comment: @unlut sorry, uint16 and after imwrite shape is (4084, 3328, 3) and dtype of pixels is uint 8

Comment: Anyway, from the shape (before imwrite) it looks like array contains a grayscale or binary image. Check if values are binary (only 0s and 1s, or 0s and 255s) or grayscale (values from 0 to 1, or values from 0 to 255)

Comment: @unlut values from ds.pixel_array are 1409, 1317, etc.

Comment: is dtype before imwrite is uint16?

Comment: No, it is uint 8, and after imwrite it is uint 16

Comment: Read your image back like this: cv2.imread("{new_img_path}.jpeg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is basically the combinations of suggestions from ***Gustavo Kaneto*** and ***unlut***.

First I need to convert from `DICOM` to `PNG` as ***Gustavo Kaneto*** has suggested. Afterwards, I need to read it as grayscale using `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` flag as ***unlut*** suggested. As a result I am getting valid pixel values:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some comments by @unlut, we know that your data is uint16 and one channel.

So I checked here with some test code...

When saving to `.jpeg`, `cv.imwrite()` clip values to uint8 range (0-255).

A simple solution is to save your file to `.png`, that accepts uint16 values.

If you need `jpeg` format, you'll have to convert your uint16 to uint8 before `cv.imwrite()`. (Note that, anyway, `cv.imshow()` will show your data (`ds.pixelarray`) correctly *before* saving the file to `jpeg`.)

#### Code to test `cv.imwrite()`

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import random as rng

# create an uint16 one-channel image with random pixel values in the range 0-65535
image16 = np.ones((200,200), dtype=np.uint16)
x, y = image16.shape
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        image16[i][j] *= rng.randint(0,65535)

# use cv to write it in JPEG and PNG formats
cv.imwrite('img16.jpeg',image16)
cv.imwrite('img16.png',image16)

# convert to uint8 then save again
image8 = image16.astype('uint8')
cv.imwrite('img8.jpeg',image8)
cv.imwrite('img8.png',image8)

cv.waitKey()
```

The results from `imwrite()` are:

[image]

Note that uint16 data saved in jpeg format results in clipping of higher values (i.e. all values greater than 255 will be 255 and show white).